# Value is not applied to Ng-Class on window resize

Tags: angularjs

I have the following controller:

```
function PlansController($scope) {

  var vm = this;
  vm.plan = null;  

  vm.show = function (plan) {
    vm.plan = plan;
  }

  $scope.$on("match", function (event, mq) {                 
    if (mq === "mobile") {
      vm.plan = "free";
      console.log(vm.plan);
    }          
  });

})();
```

The $scope.$on match fires when the media query "screen and (max-width: 31.9375em)" matches. Then I have the following:

```
<table class="plans" data-ng-class="vm.plan">
```

When I load the page with a width that matches the media query I can see that vm.plan class is applied to the table ...

The problem is when open the page in a large width. When I resize it to mobil I see in the console that the vm.plan becomes "free", so the Match condition fires and vm.plan is defined, but the CSS class is not applied to the table.

**UPDATE**

I just added an example in https://jsfiddle.net/g3wzayp3/11/

Just increase the HTML preview pane and you will see on console the value "true" when the width matches the media query ... But the class is not applied to the text ...

Any idea why?

Comment: Try `<table class="plans {{vm.plan}}">`

Comment: Just tried that ... It does not work when I resize the window even if match fires and vm.plan gets the right value ...

Comment: @Miguel may I know `$on("match"` broadcasted on `resize` event. are you doing to it manually?

Comment: That is the following directive: https://github.com/Bitponics/angular-enquire-breakpoints ... You can look at the source here: https://github.com/Bitponics/angular-enquire-breakpoints/blob/master/src/breakpoints.js. Does it help?

Comment: @PankajParkar I just added an example in https://jsfiddle.net/g3wzayp3/11/. Can you understand what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to apply the class called "free" on resize? If yes, this is not the way to do it. ng-class is used like {free: vm.plan} where vm.plan becomes true or false

Example:

```
<div ng-class="{free: should_apply}">Hello</div>
```

where free is the class that you want to apply, should_apply is a variable that evaluates to true or false

Here's a fiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/a7u1m3n6/

UPDATE:

You need to call `$scope.$apply();` in the $on method. Here's the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/g3wzayp3/12/

Comment: I have added an example

Comment: Your code does not work when I use media queries. Check the update on my question and the example in https://jsfiddle.net/g3wzayp3/11/. Increase the width of the preview pane until "true" is displayed on the console. That means the variable value was changes when the media query was matched but that has no effect on the CSS class of the text and I have no idea why.

Comment: You need to call $scope.$apply();

Comment: That works ... Is there a way to avoid using $scope.$apply() when using vm?

Comment: I don't think you can avoid it - I have observed that calling $apply is required when you do something when an event gets fired, even with sockets.